# Does cordova and xcode simulator brings accurate results

Tags: xcode, cordova

I'm going to implement an app i already have on android to ios. I don't have ios device to test, would testing it on xcode be enough ?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on which app you are building.

A fast google search will give you a hint, if you need a real device to test with or not.

There are lots of articles out there about this, for example. https://mobilelabsinc.com/blog/simulators-vs-emulators